# Is there a way to know who downloads my wordpress plugin?

Tags: wordpress

Is there a way to know who has downloaded my Wordpress plugin ? And on which blog it is used ? So far, I can track the number of downloads thanks to the Wordpress plugin platform but can't get any more detail, which would be useful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you add some code to your plugin so when its activated, it could send you an email with details from that blog, ( Although I'm sure this could be frowned upon! )

ie: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_option

```
function send_the_email(){
    // send email
    $msg .= get_option( 'admin_email' ).'\n';
    $msg .= get_option( 'blogname' ).'\n';
    $msg .= get_option( 'siteurl' ).'\n';
    wp_mail( 'you@example.net', 'Plugin Activated On: '.get_option( 'siteurl' ), $msg );
}
function myplugin_activate() {
   // activation code
   send_the_email();
}
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'myplugin_activate' );
```